# Pandas, Pivoting DataFrame By Multiple Hierarchical Columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, dataframe

I'm following

https://nikolaygrozev.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/

but am facing a different scenario for pivoting DataFrames.

The basic pivot command is like this:

```
d.pivot(index='Item', columns='CType', values='USD')
```

Now suppose my `'Item'`, belongs to two categories, `'Area'` and `'Region'`, in two other data columns. I want the pivoted result contains those three levels (`Region, Area, Item`). How can I do that?

I had been looking for answers everywhere, and had been trying methods like `'unstack', 'droplevel', 'reset_index'`, etc, but wasn't able to make them work myself.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post data by doing d.head().to_dict()?

Comment: Here's a [take](http://blog.kyleblawlor.com/posts/tidy-data/) on pivot sort of operations. Let me know if its at all helpful and I will write an answer. All the source code is at the bottom of the post if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you probably want to use `pd.pivot_table`.  Second, when you want to have multiple columns along a dimension, you need to pass them as a list (e.g. `index=['Item', 'Area', 'Region']`).

```
# Random data.
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Area': ['A', 'A', 'A',  'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                   'Region': ['r', 's', 'r', 's', 'r', 'r'], 
                   'Item': ['car' ,'car', 'car', 'truck', 'bus', 'bus'], 
                   'CType': [3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5], 
                   'USD': np.random.rand(6) * 100})

>>> df
  Area  CType   Item Region        USD
0    A      3    car      r  54.881350
1    A      4    car      s  71.518937
2    A      3    car      r  60.276338
3    B      3  truck      s  54.488318
4    B      5    bus      r  42.365480
5    B      5    bus      r  64.589411

>>> pd.pivot_table(df, 
                   index=['Item', 'Area', 'Region'], 
                   columns='CType', 
                   values='USD', 
                   aggfunc=sum)

CType                       3          4           5
Item  Area Region                                   
bus   B    r              NaN        NaN  106.954891
car   A    r       115.157688        NaN         NaN
           s              NaN  71.518937         NaN
truck B    s        54.488318        NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Ahah! `pd.pivot_table`!!! I had pursuing along the line of `d.pivot(['Item', 'Area', 'Region'], columns='CType', values='USD')`. No wonder that was so frustrating. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, BTW, @Alexander, suppose the three hierarchical levels from big to small is Region => Area => Item, then the order in your `pivot_table` command was reversed. Better correct it for someone else looking for the answers. thanks.